# The simple sentence that broke me hard

Tags: grammaticality

Somehow, I'm very confused with how to make this sentence work. Would appreciate any help.
Should it be

> You will learn what orders person A has made, as well as what things did person B keep in his mind while working on this.

or

> You will learn what orders has person A made, as well as what things person B kept in his mind while working on this.

or something entirely else?

Comment: Neither is correct. Both clauses should have the first verb **following** the subject. _You will learn what orders **person A has** made, as well as what things **person B kept** in mind while working on this_. Embedded questions do not invert subject and auxiliary verb, only real questions, with a question mark.

Answer (score 1):

SHORT VERSION:
Neither version is correct. Your first version improperly employs a question as a nominal in the last clause (*what things did person B keep in mind*), your second version makes the same mistake in the second clause (*what orders has Person A made*).

The correct version is

> You will learn what orders person A has made, as well as what things person B kept in mind while working on this.

- Note that ***has*** made,  ***made*** orders, and *keep in **his** mind* are all fairly unnatural expressions; but without more context it's impossible to suggest what would be better.

LONGER VERSION:
The underlying structure of this is:

> You will learn A as well as B.

Here both A and B must be nominals, A because it is the object of the verb *learn* and B because it is the object of *as well as*, which is complicated and controversial, but for our present purposes we can call it a *prepositional*.

There are two main sorts of clauses headed by *wh-* words:

- Questions, which are independent clauses. These employ subject-auxiliary inversion and *do-*support.

  > What orders <sub>aux</sub>**has** <sub>subj</sub>**person A** made ...?
  >   What things <sub>aux-do</sub>**did** <sub>subj</sub>**person B** keep in mind ...?
- Relative clauses, which may act as either nominals or adjuncts. These do not employ inversion or *do-*support.

  > What orders <sub>subj</sub>**person A** <sub>verb</sub>**made** ...
  >   What things <sub>subj</sub>**person B** <sub>verb</sub>**kept** in mind ...

The sort of clause you want here for both A and B is the one which may act as a nominal: a relative clause. (When it's used as a nominal it's called a *free relative clause*<sup>†</sup>, because it's not attached to a nominal which it modifies.)

> You will learn <sup>nominal/free relative</sup>[what orders person A made ]
>          as well as <sup>nominal/free relative</sup>[what things person B kept in mind ...]

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Some authorities call these *embedded questions*, and others distinguish between free relatives and embedded questions, the latter having a degree of interrogative force, as in *I wonder what he kept in mind*.</sub>

Comment: This is a very informative answer, but I think it could be improved by apprising OP that even the "correct" version of the sentence is still quite unidiomatic.

Comment: I don't think you need to offer a rewrite, just a warning (that the phrase is clunky and unidiomatic, regardless of the particular nature of the orders).

Comment: Yes, I understand, but *no actual living person* who is a native speaker of English would ever string these words together like this. Even if you're ok with "what orders he made" (I'm not, but let's leave that aside), then "kept in his mind""? No. And even if *yes* (still *no*, though), that's not how any native speaker would express the sentiment. This is how a non-native speaker not conversant in any actual idiom would phrase it, especially in an attempt to sound formal. And I think it's fair t warn non-native readers, esp OP, about that (you're an Authority saying "the correct version is").

Comment: Thanks! I'd +1 you, but I'd already done that ;)