# A noun phrase vs a question (what vs how)

Tags: grammar, questions, noun-phrases

Let's consider two phrases:

- *What makes work efficient*
- *How to say 'Hello' in Chinese*

The first one can either be a noun phrase (*What makes work efficient is careful preparation*) or a question (*What makes work efficient?*), but the second one can only be a noun phrase.

These two phrases seem to have very similar grammatical structure. The words *what* and *how* seem to have pretty similar usage in any language (not only English). So as a non-native English speaker, I would use *How to say 'Hello' in Chinese* not only as a noun-phrase, but also as a question:

- *How to say 'Hello' in Chinese?*

But this one can't be used this way. What is the reason of this difference? Is it a pecularity of the English language?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/340376/the-simple-sentence-that-broke-me-hard/340377#340377) (Stoney B's answer). Note that 'The words _what_ and _how_ seem to have pretty similar usage in [the English] language' and 'What is the reason [behind] such a fundamental difference between [the ways they are used]?' are incompatible.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 'seem to have' but nevertherless 'fundamental difference'

Comment: If they definitively have a fundamental difference in the ways they are used, they do not seem to have pretty similar usages. They may have surface similarities. / You're asking, essentially, how the different ways different wh-words are used have evolved. This is probably post-doctorate level, worthy of a published paper or three.

Comment: I removed 'fundamental'.

Comment: The problom is saying that they [behave pretty similarly in terms of grammar] when it's the grammar (the constructions they're used in) that is (perhaps puzzlingly) different. _They seem to serve very similar purposes linguistically_.

Comment: A significant difference between the two forms is the use of the infinitive in the second one. I think any construction of the form "*question-word* *infinitive* ..." can only function as a noun phrase.